# Is it an efficient method to use a framework to code a single interactive webpage in python?

Tags: django, python-3.x, html, wikipedia, wikidata

This is an open source contributor project for Wikidata's Chronic Pain project.

I would like to create a webpage that :

- Have inputboxes where the user select several wikipedia page titles (with suggestions)
- Can also take these parameters via the URL
- Get items metadata from Wikidata.
- Makes a SPARQL request to gather scholarly articles.
- Render data from Wikidata and Wikipedia, linking to various wiki pages.

The webpage will be hosted on Wikimedia fundation server. I have access to a linux container as well as a Jupyter Notebook (not sure this one is suitable for this project). It has to be coded in Python 3 since I will use Pywikibot framework to interact with Wikidata.

I'm new to programming so that I don't really know what is the best approach. I heard that it was difficult to code webpages in Python without using a framework like Django. However this page is very simple so that it may not be the most efficient to deploy Django for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NB : your question is bordering on "primarily opinion based" (which doesn't mean it's a bad question by itself but that answers might be more, well, opinions than hard facts).

This being said, "a single interactive page" doesn't mean the server code behind is just loading a static html file and sending it to the client. For example, the main UI part of our product is, technically speaking, "a single interactive page", but this "single" page is full react app and is backed by a dedicated API with a dozen entry points, which the dispatch to a whole load of backend code including database access, celery tasks etc. It *would* of course be *technically* possible to code all this with only pure wsgi or even plain old cgi code, but well, it could also be possible to write it directly in C or even assembly and no one would ever consider this a viable solution.

To make a long story short: do not even waste your time trying to code this project with plain wsgi (and let's not talk cgi), you will end up reinventing the squared wheel and everyone will hate you for this (stakeholders because you'll never deliver a robust, working product in due time and budget, and other devs because they'll now have to port the whole darn thing to a stable, mature and maintained framework).  Now if Django appears to be  overkill for this project there are much lighter frameworks like flask. Actually both are the "industry standard" and safe choices.